# Panels problem with changing the width of columns or regions

Tags: 7, javascript, panels

Some times when I try to change the width of columns or regions with `Fluid Width` the panels displays the `NAN%` and it doesn't change the width

[image]

Using Firebug I got the following error

[image]

What should I do?

---

UPDATE

It only displays this javascript error in console in `flexible-admin.js` file

```
splitter.parent.css('padding-right', (splitter.right_padding + moved) + 'px');
```

Comment: You might want to include the error as text so people can find it via search engines.

Comment: @ShawnConn I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. when the current language of the site is `rtl` such error reported. it must be `ltr`